# Can't get value from ComboBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I try to use combobox in winforms project.

Here is my code:

```
        private void ShowContoursForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           cbxSelectShape.DisplayMember = dataSetObject.ObjectShapes.ShapeNameColumn.ColumnName;
           cbxSelectShape.ValueMember = dataSetObject.ObjectShapes.ShapeIDColumn.ColumnName;
           cbxSelectShape.DataSource = dataSetObject.ObjectShapes;
        }


        private void cbxSelectShape_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var id= (int)cbxSelectShape.SelectValue;
        }
```

When I choose item from ComboBox **SelectedValueChanged** is fired,and **id** variable gets **null**.

I need to get value of selected item but I always get null in id variable.
Any idea why do I get wrong result and how to fix this code?

Comment: Try using the SelectedIndexChanged event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: While this almost certainly isn't the best way to achieve what you try to achieve, it should work IMO.

Comment: Rev what is the best way?

Comment: What's the underlying type of ShapeIDColumn.ColumnName? Is it string? If so, it looks like you're trying to cast each value from string to int.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of ComboBox this way:

```
private void cbxSelectShape_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var id= ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property of combobox to get value, associated with [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) (*ShapeID* in your case):

```
var id = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue;
```

[SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) returns index of item selected in combobox. Also if this handler used for one combobox, you don't need to cast sender - simply use your combobox variable:

```
var id = cbxSelectShape.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: @Michael are you sure you have data in your table? Set a breakpoint and watch for `cbxSelectShape.Items[cbxSelectShape.SelectedIndex]`. What do you see? BTW your `id` variable cannot be null if you are casting to `int`.